# Google maps wrong elements overlapping between different layers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polygon, geojson, layer

In my script I have two different geojson layers of polygons, the first is a grid of square polygons (fill color with transparency), the second with the black polygons.
I'd like that all the black polygons were displayed on top of the grid layer, but some of the elements (squares) of the grid layer are displayed on top of the black polygons layer (both fill and stroke, see figure), how can I avoid this?
Unfortunately I can't attach the whole code because is too big.
thank you

[image]

```
<div id='map_canvas' class='map-canvas' style='height:600px; width: 100%'></div>
```

```js
var map; 

function initMap() {    
    
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {   
          zoom: 11,       
          center: {lat: 42.917592, lng:  10.978387},      
          mapTypeId: 'satellite'      
        });     
        
        
        var layer1 = new google.maps.Data(); 
        
        layer1.addGeoJson({
          "type": "FeatureCollection",
          "features": [
              {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "id_riga": "1",
                    "id_colonna": "1",
                    "mortalita_cumulata_idw": "0.196703189773045",
                    "colore": "#EE9601"                 
                },      
            
              "geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[10.97112922366138,42.808124786915549],[10.971415164769416,42.817124833629713],[10.983640311100187,42.816913627037557],[10.983352599638527,42.807913646415301],[10.97112922366138,42.808124786915549]]]}},
            
            ... other layer1 features following.....                    
            

            ] } );          



    var layer2 = new google.maps.Data(); 
    
    
    layer2.addGeoJson({
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
              {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "id_uc": 1,
                    "nome_uc": "Balestri 1"                 
                },
              "geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[11.027800194141406,42.864195901771254],[11.0279417956916,42.865155917433597],[11.0285186045421,42.867817391501198],[11.0288973473398,42.870410334759598],[11.025149424080499,42.871365468565003],[11.0254346326017,42.872861504641698],[11.025464481234399,42.873774052223297],[11.0254338952557,42.874560702935398],[11.02539640378,42.875173685235801],[11.0254670722596,42.875574944363997],[11.029755775261,42.874675946083201],[11.0293465136471,42.872648142772398],[11.033035121733899,42.8718623127819],[11.032641177135501,42.869557804498299],[11.033828371592101,42.869176528784003],[11.0329578201918,42.864286234120598],[11.0299877946115,42.865059319950397],[11.029700669839499,42.864253988356403],[11.027978561040936,42.864199833718743],[11.027912846920032,42.864198850731832],[11.027800194141406,42.864195901771254]]]]}},
             

            ... other layer2 features following.....    

        ] } );
             
      
        
        
           layer1.setStyle((feature) => {       
            
            var colore = feature.getProperty("colore");                     
            
            return  {
              fillColor: colore,
              fillOpacity: 0.6,               
              strokeColor: "grey",
              strokeWeight: 0.8,
            };
            
          });        

      
          layer1.setMap(map);   
          layer2.setMap(map);   
    
} 
  
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try uing different zIndex for the layers

```
    layer1.StyleOptions({zIndex:1000});
    layer2.StyleOptions({zIndex:2000});
```

Comment: yes, zIndex! thank you